# Where is AUCTeX's 'circ.tex' file located?

Tags: auctex

According to [this page](https://github.com/jwiegley/auctex)

> a sample document `circ.tex' is included in the distribution

(meaning the AUCTeX distribution.)

Where is this file located? My operating system's 'search' facility doesn't find it. I'm concerned this might suggest my installation is faulty.

---

Operating system: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.3
Emacs version: 25.1.1
AUCTeX version: 11.90.0

Comment: I have it in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.3/` (Kubuntu), but I don't know where that would be in macOS.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: By the way, is there a simple way to open this file, or do I need to specify the entire path?

Comment: I have no idea.